# WHERE NOT EXISTS multiple conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

How Do I set multiple AND conditions?
ex.

```
SELECT *
FROM CONFIRMED
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM Import_Orders
    WHERE Import_Orders.Customer = CONFIRMED.Customer
        AND Import_Orders.Reference = CONFIRMED.Reference
        AND Import_Orders.[Index] = CONFIRMED.[Index]  
        AND Import_Orders.QuantityToDeliver = CONFIRMED.QuantityToDeliver  
        AND Import_Orders.DateToDeliver = CONFIRMED.DateToDeliver  

);
```

I know this works on my tables with one WHERE & AND condition but not with several.

I Need a result of two tables where the above conditions do not match. I do not have identical keys in the two tables. Now with this code I get all the results that are in table CONFIRMED.

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the expected/actual output?

Comment: What you've shown looks like a perfectly reasonable query - so you need to do more to show what actual issue you're having.

Comment: Can you explain further what you are trying to achieve? (I suspect that the answer to your question may be that you need to use ORs instead of ANDs in your subquery, but further information would be required.)

Comment: I Need a result of two tables where the above conditions do not match. I do not have identical keys in the two tables. Now with this code I get all the results that are in table CONFIRMED.

Comment: @Gerry - This could happen if, for example, the date to deliver is null.  I have extended my answer to show how that could be addressed.  However, if all the columns are non-nullable, your query should work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that you have an ID on Import_Orders, if not use any field name that is turning up empty on the query. You would be better using field names rather than *. I have added an example for Import_Orders.

```
SELECT CONFIRMED.*, Import_Orders.ID, Import_Orders.Customer
FROM CONFIRMED 
LEFT JOIN Import_Orders
ON Import_Orders.Customer = CONFIRMED.Customer
AND Import_Orders.Reference = CONFIRMED.Reference
AND Import_Orders.[Index] = CONFIRMED.[Index]  
AND Import_Orders.QuantityToDeliver = CONFIRMED.QuantityToDeliver  
AND Import_Orders.DateToDeliver = CONFIRMED.DateToDeliver  
WHERE Import_Orders.ID Is Null
```

More information

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 wow, i never knew you can use `WHERE Import_Orders.ID Is Null` like that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

Here is the syntax for multiple tables:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (...) AND NOT EXISTS (...) AND NOT EXISTS (...)
```

However, if the database is so large that you care about performance, you'll need a much less obvious syntax along the following lines:

```
LEFT JOIN Some_Table t ON (t.xxx = Main_Table.xxx)
LEFT JOIN Another_Table t2 ON (t2.xxx = Main_Table.xxx)
LEFT JOIN Yet_Another_Table t3 ON (t3.xxx = Main_Table.xxx)
...
WHERE t.id IS NULL AND t2.id IS NULL AND t3.id IS NULL
```

For one table and one composed condition, like in the SQL sample in your question:

```
LEFT JOIN Some_Table t ON
        t.xxx = Main_Table.xxx
    AND t.yyy = Main_Table.yyy
    AND t.zzz = Main_Table.zzz
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

This is expected to return rows that exist in Main_Table but do not have matching rows in Some_Table, assuming the columns `xxx`, etc., are non-nullable.

If, for example, `xxx` is nullable, here is how you need to modify the query further:

```
LEFT JOIN Some_Table t ON
        (t.xxx = Main_Table.xxx OR (t.xxx IS NULL AND Main_Table.xxx IS NULL))
    AND t.yyy = Main_Table.yyy
    AND t.zzz = Main_Table.zzz
WHERE t.id IS NULL
```

Comment: The First option returns an empty table while there should be one record in the result query. I don't know how the second works, for now i have two tables to compare with 5 different conditions

Comment: @Gerry - Wow, if I got your question now, the SQL in the question is exactly your solution.  Why do you say it does not work with multiple AND clauses?  Anyway, I'll edit my answer to add your case with an outer join as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace all the "=" with "<>" and you should get all the results that don't have a match on all criteria.

```
SELECT *
FROM CONFIRMED
WHERE EXISTS 
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM Import_Orders
    WHERE Import_Orders.Customer <> CONFIRMED.Customer
        AND Import_Orders.Reference <> CONFIRMED.Reference
        AND Import_Orders.[Index] <> CONFIRMED.[Index]  
        AND Import_Orders.QuantityToDeliver <> CONFIRMED.QuantityToDeliver  
        AND Import_Orders.DateToDeliver <> CONFIRMED.DateToDeliver  

);
```

Comment: This returns an empty table while there should be one record in the result query.

Comment: @Gerry I missed the NOT at the beginning, try it now